# SSIS : Flat File Source : FastParse property - Date column - error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image]

I have created SSIS package and reading CSV file using Flat file source control.

In CSV File : 
 1. Column name - Expiration
 2. Date format - 5/31/2015
 3. Column Data Type - DT_DATE

Now, when I set FastParse property for this column in output, it gives me below error message.

> ### TITLE: Package Validation Error
>
> Package Validation Error
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error at Data Flow [Read CSV Source File [73]]: The "FastParse" custom
>   property for "Read CSV Source File.Outputs[Flat File Source
>   Output].Columns[Expiration]" cannot be set to true.  The column data
>   type must be one of the following:  DT_I1, DT_I2, DT_I4, DT_I8,
>   DT_UI1, DT_UI2, DT_UI4, DT_UI8, DT_DBTIMESTAMP, DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,
>   DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET, DT_DATE, DT_DBDATE, DT_DBTIME, DT_DBTIME2, or
>   DT_FILETIME.
>
> Error at Data Flow [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Read CSV Source File" failed
>   validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
> Error at Data Flow [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed
>   validation.
>
> Error at Data Flow: There were errors during task validation.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Do I need to change some date format to use FastParse property? I am reading like millions of records in one operation and it is very time consuming.

So, I want to improve performance of loading data from CSV file.

Comment: are you using ISO format dates YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: @MitchWheat - I have added Data flow Task screen shot for more clarity. I am not specifically using this ISO format dates anywhere. Can you please tell me more in details where exactly I should check for this date format?

Comment: " Can you please tell me more in details where exactly I should check for this date format? " erm, in your data.....

Comment: @MitchWheat - In CSV file, date format is 5/31/2015 (MM/dd/yyy). So in flat file source, when we do suggest type, it automatically take DT_DATE type in output. I tried to change it to DT_DBDATE, but it is  not working.

Answer (score 1):

Well according to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms139833.aspx)

> By implementing fast parse, a package forfeits its ability to
>   interpret date, time, and numeric data in locale-specific formats and
>   many frequently used ISO 8601 basic and extended formats, but the
>   package enhances its performance. For example, fast parse supports
>   only the most commonly used date format representations such as
>   YYYYMMDD and YYYY-MM-DD, does not perform locale-specific parsing,
>   does not recognize special characters in currency data, and cannot
>   convert hexadecimal or scientific representation of integers.

So the only date formats you can use are YYYYMMDD and YYYY-MM-DD.